# Enable a button block programmatically?

Tags: 7

How do I enable a button block programmatically?

I've tried:

```
function openid_connect_block_info() {
  $blocks['openid_connect_login'] = array(
      'info' => t('Login Using PixelPin'),
      'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE | DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE,
      'visibility' => 1,
      'region' => 'content',
      'pages' => 'user',
  );
  return $blocks;
}
```

Comment: Looks ok. Did you try re-enabling the module that created the block?

Comment: i needed to add `'status' => 1` for it too work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a block region doesn't work unless you set `status` to `1`, and clearing your cache of course.